# Maintain state of accordion even after page refresh or transfer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want my accordion button when clicked to be still in it's current 
state, even after i refresh the page or go to a new page.

```
<div>
    <a onClick="AccFunc('BTN1')" href="#">Releases</a>
    <div id="BTN1">
         <a>January</a>
         <a>December</a>            
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function AccFunc(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    $(x).toggle();
    var isVisible = $(x).is(":visible"); 
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
}
// stored in localStorage as string, `toggle` needs boolean
var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
$(x).toggle(isVisible);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is checking the localStorage and trying to change the DOM before it is ready, so you need to add code to wait until the DOM is ready.  Further, that code doesn't know what `x` is.

I changed it to the following in a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jupjh7hL/6/) and it works as I believe you intend.

`$(document).ready(function(){
  var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
  $('#BTN1').toggle(isVisible);
})`

Comment: You can write `var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'true';` . No need in ternary operator.